# Accidentally converted my linux partition to crypto_LUKS

Tags: disk-encryption, luks, dualboot

**The problem**

I have dualboot between Windows 8.1. and OpenSUSE TumbleWeed with encrypted harddisk.
And now, when I try to boot the laptop - I get this error:

```
Welcome to GRUB!

error: no such cryptodisk found.
error: disk 'cryptouuid/6e0637a32cd0441189231bbea143a68a' not found.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue> _
```

**How I got here:**

I wanted to increase the Windows partition size, so I shrinked the Linux one. Thus some unallocated space appeared at the end of the harddisk. And I wanted to add it to the Windows partition, while the Linux one is between them. Which caused the corruption … (Didn’t know it will … so stupid …)

**The state at the moment:**

These are the partitions at the moment:

```
/dev/sda1        A6FA-7092                              vfat       SYSTEM
/dev/sda2        1A08019608017255                       ntfs       Windows
/dev/sda3        C090CFA090CF9AF4                       ntfs       
/dev/sda4        6e0637a3-2cd0-4411-8923-1bbea143a68a   crypto_LUKS 
/dev/sda5        60F8C9E0F8C9B496                       ntfs       Extended
```

sda4 is my Suse partition. I can see all my files there when I open it with file manager and enter the password for it. So my hope is that I’ll be able to restore the things as they were before and not have to re-install everything again.

**Some more info**

Result of boootinfoscript:
https://pastebin.com/Az7xaMrq

Result of `fdisk -l`:
https://pastebin.com/DC3yu05d

Result of dmesg:
https://pastebin.com/bYbg0t27

**What I tried so far:**

I followed a tutorial I found and so - I booted Manjaro from USB (cause I got only that at that moment), mounted the Linux partition on /mnt and also /dev, /sys and /proc to /mnt/(dev|sys|proc) … then I did chroot to /mnt and tried update-grub. Manjaro doesn’t have update-grub command so I found that I have to do grub2-mkconfig -o {path-to-grub.cfg}.
I tried, and got this:
https://pastebin.com/fukf70tr

=====

I'm thinking of erasing the new partition - sda5 - and convert sda4 back from crypto_LUKS. Don't know how to do the latter though.
Also thought of changing the UUID of sda4.
And also - I thought of setting the boot flag of sda4 as I see now it is set to sda2. ... But I'm afraid not to break my system even more.

Any ideas will be appreciated :)

Comment: Don't do anything with partitions until you understand exactly what you're doing and until your backups are up to date.

Comment: Thanks, @gronostaj for the advice. I have already backed up the vital stuff so even a full re-install is an option. But still - I prefer to restore the old situation.

Comment: A proper backup should let you do that relatively easily. It's good that you've pulled data from the system now before further actions, but it's 1) too late; and 2) not enough if reinstalling is too much hassle. I usually recommend avoiding any kind of repartitioning without a full disk image.